# Why is CssStyleCollection.Remove() failing here?

Tags: asp.net, css, updatepanel

I have the following event handler firing in response to a LinkButton postback inside an UpdatePanel.

```
    protected void rptImages_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //selection is only ItemCommand
        string ID = (string)e.CommandArgument;

        imgEdit.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display); //make the img visible
        imgEdit.ImageUrl = GetImageURL(ID);
    }
```

Updating the ImageUrl property works fine.  But the "display" portion of the style attribute remains present.  Watching in the debugger, the collection's Keys and Value property do not change at all.  As if the call to Remove() is simply ignored.

I added the Display style tag earlier like so:

```
imgEdit.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
```

...and this works fine.  If I immediately remove the style (same code as above), just as a test, that works also.  But the same code does not accomplish anything in the event handler.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happen if you do `imgEdit.Style["Display"] = "block";` or similar?

Comment: Yep, that worked.  What da heck.  Thanks.  Add an answer and I'll check it.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you. Added as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Add/Remove methods,you can change the style by accessing collection element directly e.g.:

```
imgEdit.Style["Display"] = "block";
```

Comment: Not sure why this works when .Remove() does not, but I'll take it!